# How to remove USB write protection in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, write-protect

I am trying to remove the write protection on my USB. I run `diskpart` command in command prompt then it had changed `read-only` yes to no. But another attribute `current read-only state` is still yes.

```
DISKPART> detail disk

SanDisk Cruzer Blade USB Device

Disk ID: 6CA38DCA
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 7     H                FAT32  Removable   7632 MB  Healthy
```

Comment: What exactly did you do with diskpart?

Comment: i follow its steps <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g13p-OvBVvY&t=13s>